# Push notifications from server-android

Tags: android

I have an android application where a user can insert data into web sql server. I want all the users to receive push notifications when someone inserts a row into database. How to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for Android is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device,
>   and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The
>   GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery
>   to the target Android application running on the target device, and it
>   is completely free.

For more info  on how to use it, refer to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial (or the official documentation) for specifics, but in overview you maintain a list of registration tokens for your users, and send the list of tokens for users you want to get a notification to Google and the send it out. Google will tell you afterward if any of those tokens are now invalid--those should be removed from your system at that point.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_push_notification.htm